# Updated dll file version on build in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to increment the file version of a the dll's in a build in visual studio without third party tools or plugins or running manually commands.

E.g. I just want to press F5 have my build start and all the dll's have a new version number.  I am not fussed if they don't get an incremented version number if they haven't changed.

Edit:

As commented below I have gone with the autobuildversion.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

In VB 2005, the version number is incremented when you Publish the app.

1. Right click on the project and choose Properties
2. Click on the Publish tab
3. At the bottom you will see Publish Version and a check box to auto
   increment it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I took a look at this but as I understand it you have to publish it every time to increment. Also I couldn't see the file version of the dll being updated, only new folders with with an incremental numbering scheme.

Comment: Try the following steps <br> Step#1 - Open the file AssemblyInfo.cs Step#2)Change [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]  Step#3)Remove [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]  Step#4)Rebuild the project and verify that the version is incremented properly by viewing the properties of the newly compiled assembly

Comment: If you need a plugin type, check this -- [link] (http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I'd seen mention of autobuildversion previously but hadn't tried it before I asked the question.  Having now tried it looks to have options to update both the assembly file version and the assembly version.  Thanks.